# What is this fungi/ mushroom we found on our walk?

Tags: fungus, mushrooms

Found this while walking in woods near our home, not sure what it is and cant seem to find it on google. Was about 8-9 inches tall. [image]

Comment: it works better to identify mushrooms in your state foraging groups better. Can we also see the gills/pours?

Comment: Sorry new to this, this is in the south east of england. And this is the only photo i managed to take unfortunately.

Comment: This might be better at the great outdoors forum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is almost certainly some species of inkcap. Beware - there are two edible (and tasty) species, but about two dozen poisonous ones!

I think this is one of the poisonous ones: the "magpie fungus" [Coprinopsis picacea](https://www.first-nature.com/fungi/coprinopsis-picacea.php).

Comment: That looks exactly like it! Thank you so much!